# Add "greater than and equal" symbol on latex table using kable and group_rows

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

As title, I am trying to use the `group_rows` function to tidy up my table as shown below, I have add the `<=` symbol at column 5 (i.e. `<=rowid`), but the symbol cannot be shown correctly when the column is used for `group_rows`, can anyone help? Thanks!

````
---
output: 
    pdf_document:
      keep_tex: true
    header-includes:
      - \usepackage{colortbl}
      - \usepackage{tikz}
papersize: a4


editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE)
options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
```

```{r cars, results='asis'}

data.df <- iris %>%
  data.frame %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(row_number()<=3) %>%
  mutate(rowid=1:n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(Species=as.character(Species)) %>%
  mutate(Species=paste0('$\\geq$',Species)) %>%
  mutate(rowid=paste0('$\\geq$',rowid)) %>%
  rename('$\\geq$rowid'='rowid')

data.df %>%
  select(-Species) %>%
  kable(.,format = 'latex',booktabs=TRUE,escape = FALSE,longtable=TRUE) %>%
  group_rows(index = auto_index(data.df$Species)) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c('repeat_header','striped','HOLD_position'))

```
````

Comment: The first escape (`\`) is getting converted to a text backslash so pandoc renders it as such.  group_rows()  defaults to escape =TRUE which isn't helping either, but that you can fix.  I Googled a bit and Yihue seems to say to use bookdown to solve pandoc escaping issues.

Answer (score 1):

The grouped row headers are put inside `\textbf{}` statement and somehow, extra text sanitation is done in the process. If you use `escape = T` inside `group_rows` and add extra backslashes it works:

```
data.df <- iris %>%
  data.frame %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(row_number()<=3) %>%
  mutate(rowid=1:n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(Species=as.character(Species)) %>%
  mutate(Species=paste0('$\\\\geq$', Species)) %>%  # extra backslashes 
  mutate(rowid=paste0('$\\geq$',rowid)) %>%
  rename('$\\geq$rowid'='rowid')

data.df %>%
  select(-Species) %>%
  kable(., format = 'latex', booktabs=TRUE, escape = FALSE, longtable=TRUE) %>%
  group_rows(index = auto_index(data.df$Species), escape = F) %>%  # escape = F
  kable_styling(latex_options = c('repeat_header','striped','HOLD_position'))
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried this earlier but the extra backslashes are giving me an out of memory error when knitting (though it is okay to the console).

Comment: Out of memory error? Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Just what it says, I didn't explore it further.